# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity with Azure ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I really hope that I don't need IdentityServer to allow users to authenticate with Azure ActiveDirectory in my asp.net core application.

Does someone have an example of using these two technologies together?

Comment: You can refer the following articles to use  AAd in an ASP.NET Core web app: [Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) and [How to use both Azure AD authentication and Identity on ASP.NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198623/how-to-use-both-azure-ad-authentication-and-identity-on-asp-net-core-3).

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need IdentityServer to use Azure AD from ASP.NET Core. To use AzureID I would recomend that you use the [Microsoft Identity Web authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web).

There are plenty of videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Microsoft.Identity.web) about the [Microsoft.Identity.web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) library.